# How to create multiple users in an Alexa Game?

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently trying to building my first Alexa skill with python. It's a game where multiple users are involved. At the beginning of the game, Alexa will ask for the name of all the participants and will memorize the names. After, it will ask questions to random participants so they can interact with each other

How can I create this command?And what course/resource would be good to learn from (other than Alexa Developper Training Resources)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. First, you could collect the names of all players in a single Intent with variable amount of slots. But I would suggest to add one player after another (with something like an AddPlayerIntent) and potentially even ask how many players there will be upfront.

Second, you could store all player names in the session [(see documentation with Python examples)](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html) and select a player randomly from that list.

Personally, I find the [sample skills on Github](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python) very helpful.